# Stop infinite loop due to 24:00:00 (00:00:00) being less than 23:59:00 instead of more

Tags: php, datetime, loops, sql-server-2008-r2, infinite-loop

I have a database that has the startTime for a task, the endTime, and how often it runs (everyMinutes).

I am taking this data into php, and using a loop writing all expected times to a separate table. The problem is when a task starts at `00:00:00` and ends at `23:59:00`. Functionally this means it runs all day. If `everyMinutes` was 15, then it would start at `00:00:00` and then run again at `00:00:15`.

The problem with my code below is that `$latestRunTime` will be `23:45:00` which is less than `$endTime` so it iterates again. However, instead of being larger than `$endTime` at the end of the loop, it is set back to `00:00:00` and I am stuck in an infinite loop. How can I mitigate this?

```
$getTaskDetailQuery = "SELECT taskID, startTime, endTime, everyMinutes FROM frequencyTable WHERE everyMinutes != '00:00:00' ORDER BY taskID ASC";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getTaskDetailQuery);
if($stmt === FALSE){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$insertQueryMulti = "INSERT INTO exactTimeScheduleTable (taskID, expectedTime) VALUES (?, ?)";
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $taskID = $row['taskID'];
    $startTimeRaw = $row['startTime'];
    $endTimeRaw = $row['endTime'];
    $everyMinutesRaw = $row['everyMinutes'];
    $startTime = $startTimeRaw->format('H:i:s');
    $endTime = $endTimeRaw->format('H:i:s');
    $everyMinutes = $everyMinutesRaw->format('H:i:s');
    $secs = strtotime($everyMinutes)-strtotime("00:00:00");
    $latestRunTime = date("H:i:s",strtotime($startTime));
    while ($latestRunTime < $endTime){
        $timeToInsertRaw = strtotime($latestRunTime);
        $dataForInsert = array($taskID,$latestRunTime);
        $execute = sqlsrv_query($conn, $insertQueryMulti, $dataForInsert);
        $latestRunTime = date("H:i:s",strtotime($latestRunTime)+$secs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the full date *and* time, at least in your loop if not in your database as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't control the data type in the database and it is a `time(7)`

Comment: Can't you just do an if statement to see if the time is 00:00:00 and if it is change it to 24:00:00?

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern That is exactly what I could do. It's been a rough morning. Thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this as the last line inside your while loop:

```
if($latestRunTime == "00:00:00") break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently checking wether the *last* run operation was within the accepted time limit, just change it to check if the *next* run operation is within the accepted time limit.

```
while (strtotime($latestRunTime)+$secs < $endTime);
```

Comment: That poses the same problem. `while ('23:45:00' < '23:59:00')` so thats true it'll run. And the next run `while ('00:00:00' < '23:59:00')` is still true. It loops infinitely

Comment: I intended the comparisons to be seconds elapsed, maybe I misunderstood your return values on $endTime. Also, would need -strtotime("00:00:00") on the left side of the statement to compensate for $secs.